# I have a problem merging navigation bar and footer html file together in my base html

Tags: python, html, css, django

I've been trying to figure out how to include the two templates in my base html and I found no success. I'm not certainly familiar with {% include %} and {% extends %} function and I believe I am not using it correctly to fix problem.

With that being said, I added my navigation bar html using {% include %} on my base html along with my footer html also using with {% include %} as shown. The result is only the footer html appeared meanwhile the navigation bar html only resulted to a horizontal line beneath the search bar.

```
{% load static %}
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>home</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/homestyle.css">
   </head>
     <body>
        {% include 'webapp/templates/pages/navbar.html' %} <!-- navigation bar html -->
        {% include 'webapp/templates/pages/footer.html' %} <!-- footer html-->
     </body>
   </html>
```

```
<!--navigation bar html -->
    {% load static %}
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>navbar</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/navbar.css">`

 `  </head>
      <body>
        <nav class="login_nav">
          <p> login </p>
        </nav>
       <hr class="solid">
        <nav>
          <img src="/static/images/user_logo.png">
            <ul class="nav_links">
              <li><a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/artists/"> apple </a></li>
              <li><a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/gallery/"> banana </a></li>
              <li><a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/about/"> grape </a></li>
           </ul>
        </nav>
      <hr class="solid">
      </body>
    </html>
```

```
[`<!--footer html -->
     {% load static %}
     <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html lang="en">
       <head>
         <meta charset="UTF-8">
         <title>footer</title>
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/footer.css">
      </head>
     <body>
     <nav>
         <p class="a"> Google </p>
         <p class="b"> 1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA </p>
     </nav>
    </body> 
    </html>`]
```

I want to merge this two together in my base html for it to have a navigation bar and footer below.

Answer (score 1):

In your included pages you are including an entire HTML page. You only want to be including the HTML tags that fit inside the overall template as you are including a subsection of the page, not IFRAMEing in an entire page - so basically remove everything except what's within your body tags in the included pages (remove the body tag as well).

You'll need to switch the CSS in the included pages to the initial template `<head>` section.

Comment: I appreciate it!

Comment: What I did was 

{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>home</title>
</head>
   <body>
      {% include 'webapp/templates/pages/navbar.html' %}
      {% include 'webapp/templates/pages/footer.html' %}
   </body>
</html>

Comment: The problem now is when I am trying to include the two html together in my base template the navigation bar was not displaying on the page however if only nav bar will be included it works not until footer file will be included

Comment: That sounds like your HTML is badly formed in some way - can you add the HTML that your browser receives, ie, by viewing source in the browser?